# I get NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID when I try to use certbot for let´s encrypt in more than one domain

Tags: server, apache2, ssl

I am following the [recommendations of Digital Ocean to configure several SSL certificates](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04) in Let´s Encrypt for more than one domain. Both domains have **www** subdomains.

The first domain I have configured with SSL is diesanromero.dev and the subdomain www.diesanromero.dev is also configured correctly. I followed the same steps for the freebooks.dev domain and everything turned out perfect, but when I try to use the **www** subdomain I get the following error:

> Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your
>   information from www.freebooks.dev (for example, passwords, messages,
>   or credit cards). Learn more NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
>   Subject: freebooks.dev
>
> Issuer: Let's Encrypt Authority X3
>
> Expires on: Aug 12, 2020
>
> Current date: May 14, 2020

Both subdomains are redirected to their respective domains. I renew the certificates and I don't get any console error, but when I try to enter **www.freebooks.dev** again I get the same error. Both **www** and **@** records point to the same IP. Also both domains point to the same IP in /etc/hosts.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?